# Display name and value (sum of all the value with same name) in pie chart android

Tags: android, realm, pie-chart

I am having problem in displaying the items and their value in pie chart. My output is as follows

[image]

As we can see the there is food slice three times. I want only one food slice along with the sum of value in those three slices. I have stored these values in arraylist. The code can be seen below:

```
Realm realm;
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> expense = new ArrayList<Integer>();

RealmResults<Credit> result = realm.where(Credit.class).equalTo("regId", userId).findAll();
    result.load();
        for (Credit p : result) {
            items.add(p.getItem());
            expense.add(p.getExpense());
    }
setPieChart();
}


private void setPieChart() {
    List<PieEntry> pieEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i<items.size();i++){
        pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(expense.get(i), items.get(i)));

        PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(pieEntries,"Spending of User");
        PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
        dataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
        data.setValueTextSize(20f);
        chart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.pieChart);
        chart.animateY(1500);
        chart.setData(data);
        chart.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Can somebody please help me to solve this problem? I had used nested loop to compare the data within the array list and add it to piechart but it didnot work..

Comment: Because you want to aggregate into a Map, and not just load into a list.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `groupBy` feature in realm implemented so far. So you should do it by yourself. I recommend you to use streams API, for that you can use this library (since Java 8  native Stream API is not supported for all API levels in Android)

https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API

In documentation you can see this part

> groupBy - groups by extractor function

```
stream.groupBy(Credit::getExpense)
```

It will group by expenses, also this lib will help you to get sum of each group.